# iphone - iOS Enterprise apps warning message

Tags: iphone

Following is the pop up message when my clients first launch the Apps

Are you sure you want to open the application "Application Name" from Developer "iPhone distribution certificate name

However, I found that some of my client's device do not pop up this warning message even they first launch the apps. So my questions are

1. By which condition the warning message will display when first launch the apps
2. Is is possible to modify the warning message and how to do it

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*By which condition the warning message will display when first launch the apps*

I think for the first time when one of your Enterprise apps is launched you see that Alert message.

*Is is possible to modify the warning message and how to do it*

No, that AlertView generated by the OS. Don't have control over it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.
Do you have any ideas why some of the user do not show the warning message when they first execute the apps?

Comment: Did they install Any of your enterprise app(s) ?

Comment: None. I have tried to install the apps in a new device, the warning message doesn't pop up too :(. It's so wired...

Comment: Is your new device connected to internet ? When your app is launched first time after install it contacts ocsp.apple.com if it cant be reached wifi / firewall that alert message isn't triggered maybe.

Comment: More finding. It seems all 4S model will pop up this warning message when they first launch the apps.